# Save and load List<Form> in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, list, savestate

I'm wondering is it somehow possible to save Form state in C# after application closing? I tried with List, and whenever I create an instance of Form that instance is added to List, and it's there until it's deleted. It works fine, and I can view, edit and delete saved forms, until Application is closed. So, considering that Form isn't serializable is there any chance to save List somehow, and load it later?

Comment: You could save your layout in XML and load that back in when you open the application up.

Comment: I think using XML for all kinds of settings is a very good design. XML is applied in many fields and it's becoming more and more important.

Comment: Is that a WinForm? Which controls/properties of the form are you looking to save?

Comment: That is a Windows Form. It contains DataGridView, TabControl, TableLayoutPanel, etc, so I want to save all. I'm not familiar with XML so I'm trying some other (probably wrong) way...

Comment: Start off by making a class which logs the instructions on how to create the modifications to your form. I would start by making an undo and redo button. If you can undo and redo modifications to your form through code then it will be very easy for you to then translate those instructions to your own custom syntax in a plain text file or xml. You are not going to be able to directly save your list and reload it you will have to create your own sort of syntax.

Comment: Alternatively, you can xml-serialize final state only. Because often saving state transitions is an overkill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Control and Form classes are not serializable.  There's a very good reason for that, *many* of their property values are heavily dependent on the execution state of the program.  Like Handle, very important but always different.  UICues, depends on whether the user pressed the Alt key.  Even simple things like Location and Size, dependent on video adapter settings and user preferences.

You would not *want* to serialize these properties.  What you want to preserve is the *data* that was used to initialize the controls.  Which of course entirely depends on your program, there is no commonality at all.  It is therefore up to you to create a class that stores the state of your UI.  You can make it serializable as needed and select your preferred way to implement serialization, there are many ways to do so.  Strictly separating the view from the model in your code is normally very important to have a decent shot at making this work.

Comment: Good points; however, in its current state this doesn't answer the question the OP has put forth. He already knows the form is not serializable and is asking for alternatives.

Comment: I specifically addressed this in the second paragraph.  When there is no commonality then there are many alternatives.  In fact, all of them will work.  I can only recommend the things that are important to make *any* of them easy to implement.